# Template specialization on boolean condition

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following class template:

```
template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo;
```

For all `D1 >= 0 && D2 >= 0` I would like to specialize this as:

```
template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo
{
    char arr[D1 * D2];
};
```

and for all `D1 < 0 || D2 < 0` as:

```
template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo
{
    char* arr;
};
```

I know it wouldn't work this exact way, since the template parameters are the same for all 3 cases. I thought about using `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional`, but I'm not sure how exactly I'd do that. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Have you looked into Algorithms? They could prove useful in this scenario.

Comment: What are your use-cases? How do you expect to be using this structure? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve (related reading [about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Comment: Oh, and having the condition be larger *or equal* to zero won't be good, as then the array size could be zero which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: It's for a matrix class, which can both have static and dynamic sizes. I like TemplateRexes solution the most. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the specializations in a separate namespace, and derive from them using `std::conditional`

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template <int D1, int D2, int dummy = 0>
class Foo
{
    char arr[D1 * D2];
public:
    // define constructors
};

template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo<D1, D2, 1>
{
    char* arr;
public:
    // define constructors
};

}

template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo
:
    std::conditional_t<(D1>=0 && D2>=0), detail::Foo<D1,D2, 0>, detail::Foo<D1,D2, 1>>
{
public:
    using Foo::Foo; // inheriting constructors
};
```

I prefer this over the solution by @JoachimPileborg to have the  specialized implementations outside the main class. E.g. if you also want to add more member functions to the class based on the same condition.

**Update**: Note that the modified solution suggested by @Columbo avoids the use of inheriting constructors (which don't even work for default constructors anyway):

```
 template<int D1, int D2>
 using Foo = std::conditional_t<(D1>=0 && D2>=0), detail::Foo<D1,D2, 0>, detail::Foo<D1,D2, 1>>;
```

Comment: Is there a better way for calling the parent class constructor than to write out the whole `conditional` term again?

Comment: @ThyposMalindos yes, I made a dummy template parameter for `detai::Foo`, (so no longer Foo1, Foo2) and then use C++11 inheriting constructors.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
template <int D1, int D2, typename=void>
class Foo {
    char* arr;
};

template <int D1, int D2>
class Foo<D1, D2, std::enable_if_t<D1 >= 0 && D2 >= 0>>
{
    char arr[D1 * D2];
};
```

If you dislike the additional, defaulted template parameter, put that into a detail namespace and make the outer `Foo` an alias template to it.